# Table aliasing not working in raw Oracle SQL queries inside Django

Tags: django, oracle, alias

Considering the following Raw SQL query made in Django 1.5 to an Oracle backend that is actually working

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EGW.TF_BSC_CELTCHH.BSC FROM EGW.TF_BSC_CELTCHH WHERE ROWNUM <= 5")
```

But if I try to use an alias for the table name like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT TCHH.BSC FROM EGW.TF_BSC_CELTCHH AS TCHH WHERE ROWNUM <= 5")
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Why table aliasing is causing such trouble in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `AS`, just type ...

```
cursor.execute("SELECT TCHH.BSC FROM EGW.TF_BSC_CELTCHH TCHH WHERE ROWNUM <= 5")
```

That way it should work.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks it works! But why AS operator is not allowed? It's not part of Oracle syntax?

Comment: @David If I remember correctly `AS` in table aliases wasn't ANSI syntax but an Informix extension (may be even older, but that's where I first saw it) that seems to be adopted my most databases now. Not Oracle though :)

Comment: By now I saw `AS` only in MySQL. In ORACLE you just use the alias - whether for tables or columns.